# How to restrict single quotes and double quotes in textfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a textfield and I want to block ",' ,&, <,> characters how will I achieve this.

I was able to block other characters using

```
inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(new RegExp('[\\&|\\<|\\>||\\>]')),
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use this `inputFormatter` the characters `'`, `"`, `&`, `<` and `>` will be blocked.

```
FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp('(\'|\"|\&|\<|\>|,)')),
```

Comment: Still allowing ", '

Comment: It is working on my machine. Can you give an example?

Answer (score -1):

This solved my issue

```
 FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp('(\’|\‘|\”|\“|\&|\<|\>|,)')),
```